# Javascript: Why is my array.filter not registering values that were pushed?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array, and I want to use `.filter` to count how many of each values there are in it, but my function seems to be ignoring any values that are `pushed` by another function.

My code looks a bit like this:

```
var arrToCheck = []

var ones =  arrToCheck.filter(function(x) { return x == 1; })
var twos = arrToCheck.filter(function(x) { return x == 2; })
var threes = arrToCheck.filter(function(x) { return x == 3; })

function checkLength(input) {
  length = input.length
  switch (length) {
    case 1:
      arrToCheck.push(1)
      break;
    case 2:
      arrToCheck.push(2)
      break;
    case 3:
      arrToCheck.push(3)
      break;
    default:
      console.log ("length too long")
   }
}
```

So, for example, if the inputs are [A, I, TO, BUT, THE, SHE], then

`arrToCheck` should return `[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3]`
`ones` should return `[1, 1]`.

But when I test it out, although `arrToCheck` returns including the pushed values as expected, the `ones` array will be empty.

The `.filter` function seems to be working though because when I enter values into the `arrToCheck` array in the source code, the `.filter` function registers those. It  just ignores any 1s that are pushed by the `checkLength` switch.

I've also tried changing the 1s from string to number in various places, but it didn't seem to make a difference (as expected).

So it seems like the individual bits are working, but they don't work together? Am I missing something?

(also, bonus question, when an array.filter function returns error "TRUE isn't a function", what did I do wrong?)

Comment: `ones should return [1, 1]` what's this?

Comment: @Anna If some answer helps you can accept It by click on big gray check button on its left side (only one answer). If you wish you can also add +10 points to author of any answer by click on gray upper triangle on answer left side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your arrays when a new input arrives, I have wrapped this update procedure on a function and called it after the a new input is pushed on `arrToCheck`. Also I have simplified the logic used by the `switch ... case` block.

```js
var arrToCheck = [];
var ones = [], twos = [], threes = [];

function updateFilters()
{
    ones = arrToCheck.filter(function(x) { return x == 1; });
    twos = arrToCheck.filter(function(x) { return x == 2; });
    threes = arrToCheck.filter(function(x) { return x == 3; });
}

function checkLength(input)
{
    length = input.length;

    if (length && length <= 3)
        arrToCheck.push(length);
    else
        console.log ("length too long")

    updateFilters();
}

// Main code:

checkLength("AA");
checkLength("AAA");
checkLength("AAAA");
checkLength("A");

console.log(
    JSON.stringify(ones),
    JSON.stringify(twos),
    JSON.stringify(threes)
);

checkLength("AA");
checkLength("AAA")

console.log(
    JSON.stringify(ones),
    JSON.stringify(twos),
    JSON.stringify(threes)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your solution was that you not put strings length into `arrToCheck` array. Here is what you probably want to get (below code use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions))

```js
var input=["A", "I", "TO", "BUT", "THE", "SHE"]

var arrToCheck = input.map(x=>x.length);

var ones =  arrToCheck.filter(x => x == 1)
var twos = arrToCheck.filter(x => x == 2)
var threes = arrToCheck.filter(x => x == 3)

// show results
j=JSON.stringify;
console.log('arrToCheck',j(arrToCheck));
console.log('ones',j(ones));
console.log('twos',j(twos));
console.log('threes',j(threes));
```

Answer (score 0):

`.filter` isn't some magical thing that constantly runs on you array, it merely executes once on the array is it was when it executes.  You'll need to run `.filter` every time you want to filter the content.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to call these lines

```
var ones =  arrToCheck.filter(function(x) { return x == 1; })
var twos = arrToCheck.filter(function(x) { return x == 2; })
var threes = arrToCheck.filter(function(x) { return x == 3; })
```

after you initialize the `arrToCheck` array.

```js
var arrToCheck = []

function checkLength(input) {
  length = input.length
  switch (length) {
    case 1:
      arrToCheck.push(1)
      break;
    case 2:
      arrToCheck.push(2)
      break;
    case 3:
      arrToCheck.push(3)
      break;
    default:
      console.log ("length too long")
   }
}

['A', 'I', 'TO', 'BUT', 'THE', 'SHE'].forEach(x=>checkLength(x))
var ones =  arrToCheck.filter(function(x) { return x == 1; })
var twos = arrToCheck.filter(function(x) { return x == 2; })
var threes = arrToCheck.filter(function(x) { return x == 3; })
console.log(ones)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the checkLength() function as written, your input.length refers to the length of the array you are passing in -- rather than the lengths of the strings inside of the array.

Allow me to suggest a slightly modified version of checkLength:

```js
function checkLength(input) {
  console.log(`input is ${input}`);
  console.log(`input.length is ${input}`);
  length = input.length
  switch (length) {
    case 1:
      arrToCheck.push(1)
      break;
    case 2:
      arrToCheck.push(2)
      break;
    case 3:
      arrToCheck.push(3)
      break;
    default:
      console.log (`unexpected length: ${length}`)
   }
}
```

If you do that and run

```
const input = ['A', 'I', 'TO', 'BUT', 'THE', 'SHE'];
checkLength(input);
```

You'll see the informative debugging information:

```
input is A,I,TO,BUT,THE,SHE
input.length is A,I,TO,BUT,THE,SHE
unexpected length: 6
```

Hope that helps get you unstuck.

When in doubt, add some `console.logs()` that can validate your understanding, or provide insight into where the code differs from your intentions.